# Libgdx Shaders - binding textures is limited in Android not in Desktop

Tags: opengl-es, libgdx, shader

I have 9 shader components, in each shader i'm binding different Texture.
In the first 7 components that i am adding to the stage the binding is working properly. the 8th and the 9th shaders are not working as if the binding not working.

The thing is that When I'm running the project in android it is not working but when i'm running the project as desktop it is working good.

in every component i'm binding different unit.

```
texture.bind(componentNumber);
```

My guess is that the problem is a configuration issue in a `AndroidApplicationConfiguration` which is the default. Because it is the only thing that is different between android and desktop
It is also might be hardware limitation.

Some have any suggestions?

Comment: I suspect you're reaching the maximum texture unit limit on Android. IIRC OpenGL only guarantees 8 texture units (0 through 7); your beefy desktop may support more, but Android might just support as little as it needs to.